# Detect mousehover and mousedown events inbetween flexbox elements

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have the following HTML/CSS:

```css
.item {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
}

.flex-row {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-row">
    <div class="item" style="width: 25%;">
        25%
    </div>
    <div class="item" style="width: 25%;">
        25%
    </div>
    <div class="item" style="width: 10%;">
        10%
    </div>
    <div class="item" style="width: 20%;">
        20%
    </div>
    <div class="item" style="width: 20%;">
        20%
    </div>
</div>

<div class="flex-row">
    <div class="item" style="width: 50%;">
        50%
    </div>
    <div class="item" style="width: 18%;">
        18%
    </div>
    <div class="item" style="width: 12%;">
        12%
    </div>
    <div class="item" style="width: 20%;">
        20%
    </div>
</div>
```

(Note, I don't actually have the above code in my project, it is generated by angular in an `ngFor`, but that is irrelevant.)

I would like to insert spacing between these divs in the flexboxes that can detect hover and mousedown events like so:

```css
.item {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
}

.spacer {
  width: 25px;
}

.spacer:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: blue;
}

.flex-row {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-row">
    <div class="item" style="width: 25%;">
        25%
    </div>

    <div class="spacer" (mousedown)="someFunction()"></div>

    <div class="item" style="width: 25%;">
        25%
    </div>

    <div class="spacer" (mousedown)="someFunction()"></div>

    <div class="item" style="width: 10%;">
        10%
    </div>

    <div class="spacer" (mousedown)="someFunction()"></div>

    <div class="item" style="width: 20%;">
        20%
    </div>

    <div class="spacer" (mousedown)="someFunction()"></div>

    <div class="item" style="width: 20%;">
        20%
    </div>
</div>

<div class="flex-row">
    <div class="item" style="width: 50%;">
        50%
    </div>

    <div class="spacer" (mousedown)="someFunction()"></div>

    <div class="item" style="width: 18%;">
        18%
    </div>

    <div class="spacer" (mousedown)="someFunction()"></div>

    <div class="item" style="width: 12%;">
        12%
    </div>

    <div class="spacer" (mousedown)="someFunction()"></div>

    <div class="item" style="width: 20%;">
        20%
    </div>
</div>
```

(again, don't worry about the syntax for the `(mousedown)` call here, just know that I want to call a function when I click on the spacer)

The issue here, is that the spacers break the flow of the flexbox (as expected). Two 25% elements no longer perfectly align with a 50% element on a later row.

I've discovered that it's easily possible to put spaces between the flex elements and preserve the alignment, using `border-box`, but I cannot figure out how to additionally track mouse hover/click events on the spaces without breaking the layout.

Comment: Are you in a position to use `display: grid` instead of flexbox?

Comment: @IronFlare This is for an internal application, so I can ensure users are using browsers with grid support. As long as the solution supports any number of elements per row, and dynamically adapting to additional elements/changing widths. So `display: grid` is fine.

Comment: Okay, and do you need to know *which* spacer is hovered over, or is the function being called the same regardless, without relying on data about the event target?

Comment: I need to know which one is being clicked. I intend on passing the index from `ngFor` into the function called.

Comment: Okay. Do you have a predefined set of possible cell widths?

Comment: Integers from 1 to 100, the spacers are for adjusting the widths on the fly. You click and drag on the spacer and it manipulates the widths of all the cells on the row. This part is already working, the spacing is just not correct.

Comment: Okay, so I had a really elegant solution, but of course, the CSS feature that is spec'd to enable it is experimental and not yet in browsers  Stand by.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note:** The first code snippet here is *non-functional* due to its reliance on an experimental feature that has exactly *zero* browser support. This may work at some point in the future, or the feature could be scrapped before it ever reaches browsers. It should not be used in production (or dev or QA) as it will fall back to `width: auto`. That being said, I wanted to include it because I already spent the time to write it and it may be helpful once it's implemented.

---

## The ideal

The most syntactically elegant solution to this would be to use the [CSS `attr` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr) to subtract from a width provided in an HTML attribute. Unfortunately, this is [not yet supported anywhere](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-attr), and so **this strategy does not work**. This is what the code might look like if it *was* supported.

```css
.item {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
  /* If this was supported, it would be great. */
  width: calc(attr(data-width length, 25px) - 25px);
}

.item:last-child {
  width: calc(attr(data-width length));
}

.flex-row {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.spacer {
  width: 25px;
}

.spacer:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<h1>This does not work because<br>attr is not fully supported :(</h1>

<div class="flex-row">
  <div class="item" data-width="25%">25%</div>
  <div class="spacer"></div>
  <div class="item" data-width="25%">25%</div>
  <div class="spacer"></div>
  <div class="item" data-width="10%">10%</div>
  <div class="spacer"></div>
  <div class="item" data-width="20%">20%</div>
  <div class="spacer"></div>
  <div class="item" data-width="20%">20%</div>
</div>

<div class="flex-row">
  <div class="item" data-width="50%">50%</div>
  <div class="spacer"></div>
  <div class="item" data-width="18%">18%</div>
  <div class="spacer"></div>
  <div class="item" data-width="12%">12%</div>
  <div class="spacer"></div>
  <div class="item" data-width="20%">20%</div>
</div>
```

---

## The realistic

Now, **there *is* a way to do this** without `attr`, but it's not as syntactically pretty. You can subtract from a width using `calc()` in the inline `style` declaration in all but the last element of the row. This strategy is also used in the previous example. If you're making the columns resizeable, you'll have to do some very basic string concatenation to ensure the `calc` statement is included in the inline style.

```css
.item {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
}

.flex-row {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.spacer {
  width: 25px;
}

.spacer:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-row">
  <div class="item" style="width: calc(25% - 25px)">25%</div>
  <div class="spacer"></div>
  <div class="item" style="width: calc(25% - 25px)">25%</div>
  <div class="spacer"></div>
  <div class="item" style="width: calc(10% - 25px)">10%</div>
  <div class="spacer"></div>
  <div class="item" style="width: calc(20% - 25px)">20%</div>
  <div class="spacer"></div>
  <div class="item" style="width: 20%">20%</div>
</div>

<div class="flex-row">
  <div class="item" style="width: calc(50% - 25px)">50%</div>
  <div class="spacer"></div>
  <div class="item" style="width: calc(18% - 25px)">18%</div>
  <div class="spacer"></div>
  <div class="item" style="width: calc(12% - 25px)">12%</div>
  <div class="spacer"></div>
  <div class="item" style="width: 20%">20%</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Applying the `calc()` statements to the inner flex items worked perfectly, thanks!